# Android: How to make sure the soft keyboard slides up smoothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

I have a `RecyclerView` and an `EditText` below it. They are the children of a vertical `LinearLayout`. When I click the `EditText`, the soft keyboard shows, but the animation isn't very smooth. It seems Android first creates dead space for the keyboard by pushing the `RecyclerView` up and then the keyboard translates into this space.

On Android 11's Messages app, I noticed that the keyboard **AND** the content above both translate together. How can I achieve a similar effect?

I'm using `AdjustResize` as my window soft input mode. I want to avoid using `AdjustPan` because it won't allow scrolling to the top of the `RecyclerView` if it contains many items. I noticed Messages can scroll to top just fine.

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animating-your-keyboard-fb776a8fb66d

Comment: Thanks. This article did the trick for me. I created a custom implementation of https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsAnimation.Callback.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I needed to pan the edit text with the keyboard. I used "AdjustUnspecified" as my window soft input mode, and did the following to achieve the wanted behavior.

1- Implement the following utility functions for convenience

```
fun Activity.getRootView(): View {
    return findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
}
fun Context.convertDpToPx(dp: Float): Float {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        dp,
        this.resources.displayMetrics
    )
}
fun Activity.isKeyboardOpen(): Boolean {
    val visibleBounds = Rect()
    this.getRootView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(visibleBounds)
    val heightDiff = getRootView().height - visibleBounds.height()
    val marginOfError = Math.round(this.convertDpToPx(50F))
    return heightDiff > marginOfError
}
```

2- In your main activity, add the following; (It is assumed that the layout id of your main activity is "main_activity_layout")

Declare a listener in the top of the class;

```
    lateinit var listener: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener
```

Then, do the following;

```
  override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    listener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        // Keep a reference to the last state of the keyboard
        private var lastState: Boolean = isKeyboardOpen()

        /**
         * Something in the layout has changed
         * so check if the keyboard is open or closed
         * and if the keyboard state has changed
         * save the new state and invoke the callback
         */
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val isOpen = isKeyboardOpen()
            if (isOpen == lastState) {
                return
            } else {
                onKeyboardStateChanged(isOpen)
                lastState = isOpen
            }
        }
    }
    getRootView().viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
}

private fun onKeyboardStateChanged(open: Boolean) {
    runOnUiThread {
        if (open) {
            val screenHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(main_activity_layout as ViewGroup)
            main_activity_layout.scrollTo(0, screenHeight / 4)
        } else {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(main_activity_layout as ViewGroup)
            main_activity_layout.scrollTo(0, 0)
        }
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    getRootView().viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
}
```

You can modify the amount of panning by modifying the scroll value here

```
   main_activity_layout.scrollTo(0, screenHeight / 4)
```